# How to prevent any player Input if the object is moving

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am creating a clone of Billiards and I cannot work out how to stop the player from interacting with and launching the ball while it is still moving; below is my attempt. I have placed an if statement that checks whether the ball is moving on both the mouseDrag and mouseUp functions. I have also tried using isSleeping() but this caused the ball to not move at all.

If possible I would like to apply this method to all of the balls and not just the cue ball; so that all balls have to have stopped before any actions may happen. This is currently in my "player" script, if I should move it a GameManager script please let me know.

```
 private void Update()
    {
            speed = rb.velocity.magnitude;
            if (speed < 0.5)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }      
  }
    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if (speed == 0)
        {
            mousePointB.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
            currDistance = Vector3.Distance(mousePointA.transform.position, transform.position);

            if (currDistance <= 3f)
            {
                spaceLimit = currDistance;
            }
            else
            {
                spaceLimit = maxDistance;
            }                      

            shootPower = Mathf.Abs(spaceLimit) * shootPowervar;

            Vector3 dimxy = mousePointA.transform.position - transform.position;
            float difference = dimxy.magnitude;

            mousePointB.transform.position = transform.position + ((dimxy / difference) * currDistance * -1);
            mousePointB.transform.position = new Vector3(mousePointB.transform.position.x, mousePointB.transform.position.y, -0.8f);

            shootDirection = Vector3.Normalize(mousePointA.transform.position - transform.position);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (speed == 0)
        {
            mousePointB.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;

            arrow.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            circle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;


            Vector3 push = shootDirection * shootPower * -1;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(push, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: you want to avoid to use  mouseDrag and mouseUp when ball is moving? the fact to test speed==0 is not functional, i suppose its the speed of ball?

Comment: I want the player to not be able to the ball in anyway while it is moving; this is my attempt at it because I'm not entirely sure what I need to do. It is the speed of the ball but I am not entirely sure if it works

Comment: I would say that by returning soon if the speed is more than a margin value. F.E. 

if (speed > 0.1f) return;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your test speed == 0 is not functional, you could record the last position of the ball, and set a boolean isMoving = true, if actual position of ball is different thant the last, then record the lastposition and so on

```
Vector3 LastPosition;
bool isMoving;

void Update()
{
   isMoving = BallPosition == LastPosition;
   :
   :
}

void OnMOuseDrag()
{
    if(!isMoving) return;

}  

void OnMOuseUp()
{
    if(!isMoving) return;

}
```

Comment: Would I be able to use tags to check whether other objects are moving, such as stripes or solids, or would it be better to have that on a separate script and then call that method and use it in this class?

Comment: have you the same script for cue ball and other balls? and each ball has its script linked?  the tag are uniques for each ball?

Comment: While your solution worked it took too long for the ball to stop moving; instead I used rigidbody.velocity.magnitude and checked whether it was <= 0.1 and that worked. Your solution was a bit too accurate

Comment: i suggest you to use a ball manager script to stock if each ball is moving or no, in a static list or other static collection.  so if any of item isMoving the player cant interact...